# Remove strings from PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to search an array with words like "new" "York" "other" "thing",
and combine only the ones that make up the words of a state.

In this example, I want the matches for states to be combined in the array:

From this:

```
<?php 
$states = array("new york", "Nevada");
$names = array("something", "green", "something", "yellow", "new", "york", "new","jersey");
```

To this:

```
$names = ( "something", "green", "something", "yellow", "new york", "new jersey");
```

Hence altering the the names array to combine the states.

Comment: In your example, how does it know to create *New Jersey*? If the `$states` array contained all 50 states, how would it know whether **new** applied to *New York* or *New Jersey*?

Comment: Should there be New Jersey in states array? Do i get your logic?

Comment: Two things need to be clarified here. 1. Should we check the two simultaneous array values only? e.g: "new" and "york. And not "green" and "yellow" since they aren't simultaneous entries?  2. Based on what logic are we getting new york? $states doesn't have new york

Comment: @ObjectManipulator States does have new york `$states = array("new york", "Nevada");`

Comment: Sorry, I meant new jersey

Comment: I want  to combine those right next to each other  so like "new", "york" to become "new york"  where  "new" "haven" "york"  will remain as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before viewing the solution, take a look at the two assumptions made:
1. Concurrent array elements are checked in $names.
2. Checking is made with respect to $states.

```
$states = array("new york", "Nevada");
$names  = array("something", "green", "something", "yellow", "new", "york", "new","jersey");
foreach($names as $k => $v) {
    $combined_names = $names[$k]." ".$names[$k+1];
    if (in_array($combined_names, $states)) {
        $names[] = $combined_names;
        $names[$k] = $names[$k+1] = '';
    } 
}
$result = array_values(array_filter($names));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => something
  [1] => green
  [2] => something
  [3] => yellow
  [4] => new
  [5] => jersey
  [6] => new york
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can solve the "New Jersey" issue in the comments, the following will map one array of words onto a target array (in this case states). The resulting array is then de-duplicated and re-indexed.

If the names need to only match whole words in the target strings, the `stripos` test can be changed to a more advanced `preg_match`;

```
<?php 
$states = array("new york", "Nevada");
$names = array("something", "green", "something", "yellow", "new", "york", "new","jersey");

$result = array_map(function ($e) use ($states) {
    foreach ($states as $state) {
        // The moment a match is found, return it
        if (stripos($state, $e) !== false)
        {
            return $state;
        }
    }

    // If no match was found, fall back to the word in the original array
    return $e;
}, $names);

print_r(array_values(array_unique($result)));
```

=

```
Array
(
    [0] => something
    [1] => green
    [2] => yellow
    [3] => new york
    [4] => jersey
)
```

Comment: sorry, no I wanted to just combine anywhere it was a state ... so merge all of the state names if they are next to each other